# how to read string meaning start by specific char and end by specific char in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist

I'm making a dictionary, first in simple dictionary i save word in `text.txt` file with just some of words, like

```
chicken     a animal like duck
duck        a animal like chicken
```

Because 2 word separate by more than 2 spacebar, i used `split` to save in `arraylist`. But I need to make a dictionary with huge database in a text file, so I got a file in the Internet. But a problem is, it have multi meaning and start with specific char, it looks like this:

```
@chicken
*noun
-a animal like duck
-it produce egg
@duck
*noun
-a animal like chicken
-it have egg too
@....
*..
-..
-..
```

So I think I can't save to arraylist anymore and **I really don't know how to read this, like when I input chicken, it so multi meaning**
How can i just type `chicken` it will show all meaning?

```
*noun
-a animal like duck
-it produce egg
```

Comment: I guess the starting point is to find the specification for your input file. Only then will you be able to make an attempt. Once you've done so, show us your working and we can help.

Comment: As mentioned, identify the format of the file and then define how to parse that format. Create a class to hold the data, word and a list of explanations or use a collection class as a HashMap with the word as a key and an ArrayList as the value.